# AngularJS and Java communication

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, hibernate, components

I've just started learning about software components but I'm completely new to this subject and I was asked to make an AngularJS application and at the same time manage the data with a hibernate application in Java, so I'd like to know What's the best way to connect my AngularJS app to my hibernate app, I may say I'm kind of lost in the subject.

Comment: I suggest using Spring in your backend, expose REST web services, consume them with your AngularJS app. There are many tutorials on Spring+AngularJS, google them.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do research about that

Comment: If necessary we can give a sample kind of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to go with Spring framework. For build/dependencies, use maven. AngularJS/Html/JS as front end tech, hibernate+JPA/Java/Spring as server side tech. Use of JPA makes things pretty simple. Initially it may look a bit puzzling for new folks, but slowly it all looks such a great things to work on.